# Unable to load wsdl through .net web service studio

Tags: .net, soap, wsdl

One of our clients has developed wsdl. I can access wsdl on browser but unable to load wsdl through .net web service studio. getting below error can you please help in this regard what is the reason of this error.

[image: Error Image]